# How do I enable C++ intellisense for a Bazel project in VS code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense, bazel

I would like to enable intellisense for my C++ project that is being built with bazel in VS code.

There used to be a an [extension](https://github.com/dprogm/vscode-bazel-tools) that could do it, but it has been discontinued since the release of the official [vscode-bazel](https://github.com/bazelbuild/vscode-bazel) extension which lacks this ability.

Answer (score 6):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/vscode-bazel/issues/179) on vscode-bazel regarding this feature.

Fortunately, [somebody](https://github.com/bazelbuild/vscode-bazel/issues/179#issuecomment-580685720) pointed to an other tool [bazel-compilation-database](https://github.com/grailbio/bazel-compilation-database) which can automatically generate a `compile_commands.json`.

Once you have generated that file, add it to your `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` file by adding the line

```
"compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/compile_commands.json"
```

Intellisense should now be enabled assuming you have [vscode-cpptools](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools) extension installed.